# My external hard drive fell down and now shows a code 43 error

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-detection, physical-damage

My Seagate Backup Plus Hub external hard drive fell down and now stays undectected by Windows 10. In the device manager, it is shown as an unknown USB device with an error 43. I tried to update the driver, to uninstall the drive and reinstall it, to no avail.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you looked at Seagate, "error 43 and Windows" ? It may have crashed or... https://www.seagate.com/support/kb/windows-has-stopped-this-device-because-it-has-reported-problems-code-43-220071en/

Comment: It might be that the drive has shifted inside the enclosure and is no longer actually connected. You may have to open it up and check.

Comment: @vssher Good idea. So I installed SeaTools, but the disk isn't even detected.

Comment: I was wondering, was it plugged in when it fell? If yes, then I'm affraid you have lost the hard disk. Your English is very good, by the way. I would one day love to see Paris, France. PEACE!

Comment: @Mokubai It seems, the case cannot be opened non-destructively, so I'm hesitating... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qB24JlZoEWg